# How to obtain the PDF of $Z=\ln Y+N$ with the density of $Y$ and $N$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Now I have $z = \ln\theta + n$, and $$f_{\theta}(\theta) = \begin{cases}1 &\text{if } 0<\theta< 1 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$
and
$$f_{n}(n)=\begin{cases}e^{-n}&\text{if } n \ge0 \\0& \text{else} \end{cases}$$

How to get pdf of $z$, that is $f(z)$?

I tried to use $$f(z) = \int f(\theta)f(n) \, dn$$

But it is not like $z = x + y$, so I cannot use convolution (substitute $x = z - y$). Then how to solve it please?

Comment: In expressions like $\Pr(X\le x)$ the reason for using a capital letter for $X$ and a lower-case letter for $x$ exist.  Perhaps the notation $f_N(n)$ would convey what you mean, where the random variable is $N$ and the argument to the probability density function is $n$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are using the same notation twice. One should write $f_\theta$ and $f_n$ for different densities.

Second, the question is ill-posed and notations are not clear. You might want to write instead:

> Suppose $Y$ and $N$ are two *random variables* with densities respectively $f_Y$ and $f_N$ defined as
>   $$f_{Y}(y) = \begin{cases}1 &\text{if } 0<y< 1 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$
>   and
>   $$f_{N}(n)=\begin{cases}e^{-n}&\text{if } n \ge0 \\0& \text{else} \end{cases}$$
>   Define $Z=\ln Y+N$. What is the PDF of $Z$?

Third, there are some simpler related questions you could try:

- Do you know the definition of PDF of $Z$? Do you know that there is a function closely related to the PDF of $Z$?
- Can you find the [Cumulative distribution function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function)(CDF) of $Z$ by its *definition*?
- What is $P(Z\leq z)$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your correction. I was not rigorous enough. But before I calculate CDF, I have to know its pdf right? You mean I can directly gat the CDF and then differentiate it?

Comment: Yes, I am also confused by the meaning of pdf of Z.

Comment: Do you know the definition of CDF?

Comment: it's the probability that the variable less or equal than something. $F(z_{0})$ is the probability $z\lez_{0}$

Comment: This is $z\le z_{0}$